# JS search returned xhr.responseText for div then remove div

Tags: javascript, html, removeclass, responsetext

I would like to search a xhr.responseText for a div with an id like "something" and then remove all the content from the xhr.responseText contained within that div.

Here is my xhr code:

```
function getSource(source) {
    var url = source[0];
    var date = source[1];
    /****DEALS WITH CORS****/
    var cors_api_host = 'cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com';
    var cors_api_url = 'https://' + cors_api_host + '/';
    var slice = [].slice;
    var origin = self.location.protocol + '//' + self.location.host;
    var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        var args = slice.call(arguments);
        var targetOrigin = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/i.exec(args[1]);
        if (targetOrigin && targetOrigin[0].toLowerCase() !== origin &&
            targetOrigin[1] !== cors_api_host) {
            args[1] = cors_api_url + args[1];
        }
        return open.apply(this, args);
    };
    /****END DEALS WITH CORS****/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", cors_api_url+url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var resp = xhr.responseText;
            var respWithoutDiv = removeErroneousData(resp);
        }
        else{
            return "Failed to remove data.";
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

remove div here:

```
/*This must be in JS not JQUERY, its in a web worker*/
function removeErroneousData(resp) {
    var removedDivResp = "";

    /*pseudo code for removing div*/ 
    if (resp.contains(div with id disclosures){
       removedDivResp = resp.removeData(div, 'disclosures');
    }

    return removedDivResp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the response in a div and then search for that div you want empty its content.

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var resp = xhr.responseText;
            $('div').attr('id', 'resp').html(resp);
            $('#resp').find('disclosures').html('');
            //var respWithoutDiv = removeErroneousData(resp);
        }
        else{
            return "Failed to remove data.";
        }
    }

Comment: I need it to be in JS not JQuery. Thanks for the response though.